# Lots of problems with the editing filter area

Tags: support, new-nav

#### Navigating with the tags list doesn't work most of the time.

When a few tags are added, not all tags are shown.

[image]

And there is no way to edit the tags before `hl7-fhir`. 
When I set the focus in the tags list, I can navigate through the tags using the keyboard, but most of the time it loses the focus after a few characters. After many tries it eventually works.

#### Some filters don't show any results

[image]

For example these tags

`angular-dart dart-pub dart-html dart-io dart-js-interop dart-angular-templates dart-analyzer dart-async dart-webui dart-web-toolkit dart-dev-compiler angular2-dart dart-polymer`

This is also for shorter tag lists. 
I wasn't able to figure out if a single tag or a specific combination of tags caused it.

I had this issue a while ago with the tags `angular angular2`, where one was made a synonym of the other which resulted in not getting any results any more.

#### Saving doesn't seem very reliable.

Quite often after clicking `save` and reloading the page, tab names, whole tabs, or tags are lost.

Comment: *Some filters don't show any results* -  You have it set to require a question to have 'all' of the tags instead of 'any'.

Comment: Also, can you please tell us your browser/OS that you're getting the other issues?

Comment: @BSMP thanks that fixed the no search result issue. It's Chrome 60 on OSX 10.12.6. I had the same on Linux since months. I posted a support request about a year ago and it was eventually improved a little. About 3 months ago I switched to Mac and here it's exactly the same behavior.

Comment: Also when I reload on my phone, I don't get any of the updates I made on my computer. Perhaps some caching issue that resolves itself after a while. Might be related to the last bullet though.